# Improve draw speeds for WPF Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have created a Listbox in WPF, where I plot 2D points randomly when the user clicks Generate. In my case I'm going to be plotting several thousand points when the user clicks Generate. I noticed when I generate around 10,000 or even 5,000 points, it takes forever. Does anyone have advice on ways to speed this up?

Is it possible to only trigger the update to take place once all points have been generated, assuming that due to the ObservableCollection it's attempting to update the listbox visuals every time a new point is added to the collection.

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace plotting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            CityList = new ObservableCollection<City>
            {
                new City("Duluth", 92.18, 46.83, 70),
                new City("Redmond", 121.15, 44.27, 50),
                new City("Tucson", 110.93, 32.12, 94),
                new City("Denver", 104.87, 39.75, 37),
                new City("Boston", 71.03, 42.37, 123),
                new City("Tampa", 82.53, 27.97, 150)
            };
        }

        private ObservableCollection<City> cityList;
        public ObservableCollection<City> CityList
        {
            get { return cityList; }
            set
            {
                cityList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CityList");
            }
        }

        // INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

        public async Task populate_data()
        {
            CityList.Clear();
            const int count = 5000;
            const int batch = 100;
            int iterations = count / batch, remainder = count % batch;
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                int thisBatch = _GetBatchSize(batch, ref remainder);

                for (int j = 0; j < batch; j++)
                {
                    int x = rnd.Next(65, 125);
                    int y = rnd.Next(25, 50);
                    int popoulation = rnd.Next(50, 200);
                    string name = x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString();
                    CityList.Add(new City(name, x, y, popoulation));
                }

                await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
            }
        }

        public void populate_all_data()
        {
            CityList.Clear();
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            {
                int x = rnd.Next(65, 125);
                int y = rnd.Next(25, 50);
                int count = rnd.Next(50, 200);
                string name = x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString();
                CityList.Add(new City(name, x, y, count));
            }
        }

        private static int _GetBatchSize(int batch, ref int remainder)
        {
            int thisBatch;

            if (remainder > 0)
            {
                thisBatch = batch + 1;
                remainder--;
            }
            else
            {
                thisBatch = batch;
            }

            return thisBatch;
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            await populate_data();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
        }

        private void Button_Click_All(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            populate_all_data();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
        }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // east to west point
        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        // north to south point
        public double Latitude { get; set; }

        // Size
        public int Population { get; set; }

        public City(string Name, double Longitude, double Latitude, int Population)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Longitude = Longitude;
            this.Latitude = Latitude;
            this.Population = Population;
        }
    }

    public static class Constants
    {
        public const double LongMin = 65.0;
        public const double LongMax = 125.0;

        public const double LatMin = 25.0;
        public const double LatMax = 50.0;
    }

    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static double Remap(this double value, double from1, double to1, double from2, double to2)
        {
            return (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;
        }
    }

    public class LatValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        // Y Position
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double latitude = (double)value;
            double height = (double)parameter;

            int val = (int)(latitude.Remap(Constants.LatMin, Constants.LatMax, height, 0));
            return val;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class LongValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        // X position
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double longitude = (double)value;
            double width = (double)parameter;

            int val = (int)(longitude.Remap(Constants.LongMin, Constants.LongMax, width, 0));
            return val;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="plotting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:plotting"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="500" 
        Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:LatValueConverter x:Key="latValueConverter" />
            <local:LongValueConverter x:Key="longValueConverter" />
            <sys:Double x:Key="mapWidth">750</sys:Double>
            <sys:Double x:Key="mapHeight">500</sys:Double>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5" >
        <Button Content="Generate Batches" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <Button Content="Generate All" Click="Button_Click_All"></Button>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CityList}">
            <!-- ItemsControlPanel -->
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Longitude, Converter={StaticResource longValueConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource mapWidth}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Latitude, Converter={StaticResource latValueConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource mapHeight}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

            <!-- ItemTemplate -->
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<Button Content="{Binding Name}" />-->
                    <Ellipse Fill="#FFFFFF00" Height="15" Width="15" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#FF0000FF"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**Update 1:**
Assign the ObservableCollection once all the points have been made.

```
public void populate_data()
{
    CityList.Clear();
    Random rnd = new Random();

    List<City> tmpList = new List<City>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        int x = rnd.Next(65, 125);
        int y = rnd.Next(25, 50);
        int count = rnd.Next(50, 200);
        string name = x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString();
        tmpList.Add(new City(name, x, y, count));
    }
    CityList = new ObservableCollection<City>(tmpList);
}
```

This change does not affect the UI experience much, if at all. Is there a way to allow the UI to update as the objects are added?

End goal is plotting just points representing each coordinate in 2D space.

[image]

Comment: Generating 10,000, or 5,000, or even 1,000 listbox item containers is going to be resource intensive. That is why the `ListBox` uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` as its default panel - it only generates containers for objects that are actually on screen. I assume you are not going to require all of your points be visible at the same time - if that is the case I would look into creating a custom virtualizing panel for your points.

Comment: It would probably be better to just replace the CityList at one time rather than have the individual CollectionChangedEvents going off and sparking redraws for every single city added.

Comment: In most cases all points will be visible at the same time

Comment: I wonder if there would be a way to have a progress bar indicating the process however update the ui every 10 percent or something from a background thread

Comment: _"I wonder if there would be a way to have a progress bar"_ -- of course there would be. You can just populate the data asynchronously, so the UI gets opportunities to update. But, since you say the points are mostly all visible all the time anyway, wouldn't the progress of adding the elements suffice as progress indication? Then you don't need the progress bar per se, just to move the population code off the UI thread (or, more likely, just `Task.Yield()` periodically in the UI thread...since most of the work is UI work, you're just going to wind up in the UI thread all the time anyway).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not really clear what question you want an answer to. The only not-too-broad question you've asked is whether there's a way to delay updating until all the elements have been added, and the closest you can get to that is to build the collection and not set the bound value until it's filled. Your code right now is effectively delaying much of the UI work until the data's been populated, just by virtue of blocking the UI thread.

Comment: What would you suggest I do then just to improve my situation? I'll change the code to set the observablecollection once all the new points are created. But what should I do following that to improve performance. I'll test that first and report back

Comment: @PeterDuniho so I've updated my code to only assign the observable collection once all the points have been created. However How would i go about implementing the suggestion you made here:  just to move the population code off the UI thread (or, more likely, just Task.Yield() periodically in the UI thread...since most of the work is UI work, you're just going to wind up in the UI thread all the time anyway)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've posted an answer addressing your specific question.

Comment: Seeing that some data points have names like Denver, you probably work with geo data, so [ZoomableCanvas](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaelr/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items/) may give you some hints. OTOH, if you'd like to draw it yourself, you can check out article which I'd call [ten million pixel challenge in WPF](http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-high-performance-graphics-in-wpf.html). I recently posted a small set of hints and a collection of that and some other very related articles. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48074757/717732 for the whole post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to only trigger the update to take place once all points have been generated, assuming that due to the ObservableCollection it's attempting to update the listbox visuals every time a new point is added to the collection.

Actually, that's not a correct assumption. In fact, `ListBox` already will defer updates until you're done adding items. You can observe this by modifying your `Click` handler (having added the appropriate `ElapsedToIdle` property to your window class and bound it to a `TextBlock` for display, of course):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    populate_data();
    ElapsedToIdle = sw.Elapsed;
}
```

The problem is that even though it's deferring updates, when it finally gets around to processing all the new data, it still does that in the UI thread. With the above, I see the elapsed time at around 800 ms on my computer. So, the `populate_data()` method is only taking that long. If, however, I change the method so it measures the time until the UI thread returns to an idle state:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var task = Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => sw.Stop(), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
    populate_data();
    await task;
    ElapsedToIdle = sw.Elapsed;
}
```

…the actual time is in the 10-12 second range (it varies).

From the user point of view, it may be less important that the operation takes so much time, than that the entire program appears to lock up while the initialization is taking place. This can be addressed by changing the code so that the UI gets chances to update while the initialization occurs.

We can modify the initialization code like this to accomplish that:

```
public async Task populate_data()
{
    CityList.Clear();
    const int count = 5000;
    const int batch = 50;
    int iterations = count / batch, remainder = count % batch;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        int thisBatch = _GetBatchSize(batch, ref remainder);

        for (int j = 0; j < batch; j++)
        {
            int x = rnd.Next(65, 125);
            int y = rnd.Next(25, 50);
            int popoulation = rnd.Next(50, 200);
            string name = x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString();
            CityList.Add(new City(name, x, y, popoulation));
        }

        await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
    }
}

private static int _GetBatchSize(int batch, ref int remainder)
{
    int thisBatch;

    if (remainder > 0)
    {
        thisBatch = batch + 1;
        remainder--;
    }
    else
    {
        thisBatch = batch;
    }

    return thisBatch;
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    await populate_data();
    ElapsedToIdle = sw.Elapsed;
    ButtonEnabled = true;
}
```

This adds 4-5 seconds to the initialization time. For obvious reasons, it's slower. But, what the user sees is a gradually populated UI, giving them better feedback as to what's going on, and making the wait less onerous.

For what it's worth, I also experimented with running the initialization in a background task while the UI was allowed to update. This produces something in between the above two options. That is, it's still slower than initializing without updates, but it's a bit faster than the initialize-and-update-in-UI-thread option, because there's just a bit of concurrency involved (I implemented it so that it would start a task to compute the next batch of objects, and then while that task was running, add the previous batch of objects and wait for that update to complete). But, I probably wouldn't use that approach in a real program, because while it's a bit better than just doing everything in the UI thread, it's not *that* much better, and it significantly increases the complexity of the code.

Note that adjusting the batch size has important effects on the trade-off between responsiveness and speed. Larger batch sizes will run faster overall, but the UI is more likely to stall and/or be completely unresponsive.

Now, all that said, one important question is, do you really need to use `ListBox` here? I ran the code using a plain `ItemsControl` instead, and it was 2x to 3x faster, depending on the exact scenario. I assume you are using the `ListBox` control to give selection feedback, and that's fine. But if speed is really important, you might find it makes more sense to use `ItemsControl` and handle item selection yourself.

Comment: (sorry for copying comment from the main question, but I think you may be also interested in looking there) - Seeing that some data points have names like Denver, so [ZoomableCanvas](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaelr/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items/) may help. OTOH, if drawing it by yourself, see [ten million pixel challenge in WPF](http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-high-performance-graphics-in-wpf.html). I recently [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48074757/717732) a small set of hints and a collection of that and some other very related articles.

Comment: @Peter the batch method is a great idea, it appears simple and effective. I would curious if you would be open to sharing you method using the Items control. I do not have a problem handling the select stuff myself. I would rather have improved speed like you mentioned. Ideally i wouldn't actually be displaying all the coordinates, instead i would show a circle indicator at each point. Similar to the one i have added to the OP.

Comment: I changed mine to use an ItemsControl and it appears slows. so I'm curious to know how you got it to be faster. I've updated my code to show you what i have so far! I don't see a big speed improvement in the itemscontrol.

Comment: I didn't do anything special to switch to `ItemsControl`. I just changed the XAML, replacing "ListBox" with "ItemsControl", and removing the property and setter that weren't valid for `ItemsControl` (`SelectionMode` and `BorderThickness`). Main difference between your current code (for future reference, please do not _change_ the question) and mine is that you've removed the `IsItemsHost` and width/height from the `ItemsPanelTemplate` canvas, and are now templating the items instead of just displaying their name.